# JAX-WS: How to Exclude a "member/field" in a Response Object (WS Response) that is inherited?

Tags: jax-ws

I have a WebService that returns as the result of the Invokation of the Web-Service a ResponseObject called "`CustomerResponse`". When I implement this object "from scratch" everything works fine: My implementation in this case only contains all the needed "Simple Types" like Strings, Integers but NO Object references/associations.

However what I wanted  to do is, "reuse" existing Objects. I have in my domain-model a "`Customer`" Object that is used in the Application itself. Instead of stupidly more or less cloning the `Customer` into the "CustomerReponse" object (by manually typing again all the members/fields), I wanted to base the `CutomerResponse` object on the `Customer` Object by extension:

```
class CustomerResponse extends Customer
```

==> The Problem is that now `CustomerResponse` contains some "internal" fields that were inherited from the `Customer` Object (like DatabaseID, Security-Stuff) that I do not want to expose via the Web-Service. Furthermore (and thats currently the main problem") `Customer` also contains a lot of "object references/associations" to other objects like `Address`, `Orders`, `History` that I do not want to expose via the Webservice either. (It seems that Apache CXF "evaluates" the whole Objectgraph and tries to include them in the ResponseObject...)

==> Is it possible to "Extend" WebService Response Objects based on existing Objects and somehow **exclude** some "members/fields" of the extended supertyp? (So I want to exclude some members (like the DatabseID) and all of the "object associations" like (Address/Orders/Histroy)..
How can I acomplish this, with what annotations and procedures?

Thank you very much!!
Jan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The @XmlTransient annotation is used to hide members which you do not want shown.  You should be able to annotate these members, and they won't be bound.  Alternatively, change your @XmlAccessorType to [XmlAccessType.NONE](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html#NONE) and only specifically annotated methods will be bound to XML.

Comment: Hello KT, thank you very much for your answer. Well I actually tried @XMLTransient but it didnot work somehow. (Apache CXF nevertheless seemed to at least "crawl" the objectgraph on loading the Webservice and threw some exceptions (as My objectgraph has some identically named inner static Enums...). I will try again and will trry your XmlAccessType.NONE. Tanks!

Answer (score 11):

Regarding the @XmlTransient annotation, I found out that you need to put it on the getter method of the field you want to hide.

```
public class InputBean
{
    private String fieldShow;
    private transient String fieldHide;

    public String getFieldShow() {
        return fieldShow;
    }

    public void setFieldShow(String fieldShow) {

        this.fieldShow = fieldShow;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public String getFieldHide() {
        return fieldHide;
    }

    public void setFieldHide(String fieldHide) {
        this.fieldHide = fieldHide;
    }
}
```

In the example, "fieldHide" will not be visible on the service xsd.

Comment: Good spot. You need both `transient` for your field and `@XmlTransient` for the getter.

Comment: Worked for me without `transient`

Comment: Not working for boolean types. However if you annotate your boolean field it works.

Answer (score -10):

C# solves this problem with partial classes. I don't know how to do it with jax-ws.